# Time complexity of a Deterministic Selection algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

I recently watched a video about how we can make a selection algorithm run in O(n) time and I am confused about one step in the process of making the algorithm.

The video says that we should partition the set of numbers or array into n/5 groups of 5 elements and the remaining elements in another group. Then we find the median of each group. Then we find the median of the medians and use it as a pivot and so on.

However to find the median of each group we have to sort the groups first. The video says use insertion sort or merge sort, but aren't those algorithms O(nlogn)? So how could the overall running time be O(n) if sorting already takes O(nlogn)?

Here is the video for reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YU1HfMiJzwg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the set of numbers or array into n/5 groups of 5 elements and the .... Then we find the median of each group... However to find the median of each group we have to sort the groups first. The video says use insertion sort or merge sort, but aren't those algorithms O(nlogn)? So how could the overall running time be O(n) if sorting already takes O(nlogn)?

Not entirely true. Since sorting a group of 5 is only `5log(5)` and we did it in `n\5` time. That would be `n*5/5 log(5) = nlog(5)`. That's still linear.

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong before edit.

I've read sets of n/5 elements, instead of n/5 sets of 5 elements.

Sorting N/5 sets of 5 or less elements is `O(N/5 * 5*log(5))`, which is linear in complexity time.

Comment: I think i'm missing something here, in my lecture slides it says that the running time is O(n) as well..

Comment: I misunderstood what you said, and edited the answer, but invisal is right.